# How to check if two rectangles collide over the axis

Tags: java, collision-detection

I think I've got some kind of duplicate question, but I just can't figure it out.

So I got a `Region` class. This class contains four attributes. `aX`, `aY` and `bX`, `bY`.
Now I want to produce a method `doesCollide(Region other)`. I've tried many things, but can't get it to work. I think it is, because the regions refer to a region on a minecraft world, where the to points `a` and `b` can be negative. Can someone help me out?

For better understanding I did a little drawing of a scenario:
[image]

What I've tried:

Due to a hint of a user I tried it using the `java.awt.Rectangle` class:

```java
        Rectangle thisRectangle = new Rectangle((int) aX, (int) aY, Math.abs((int) bX) - Math.abs((int) aX), Math.abs((int) bY) - Math.abs((int) aY));
        Rectangle otherRectangle = new Rectangle((int) other.aX, (int) other.aY, Math.abs((int) other.bX) - Math.abs((int) other.aX), Math.abs((int) other.bY) - Math.abs((int) other.aY));
        return thisRectangle.intersects(otherRectangle);
```

(I absolutely don't know if I've done it right)

I tried something that I would say is the "standard" thing used here:

```java
return aX < other.bX && bX > other.aX & aY < other.bY && bY > other.aY
```

Well, didn't work either.

Comment: Can  you talk a little about what you tried, including showing the code you wrote? Because the standard rectangle intersection checks should work perfectly fine here. You know your corner points, so you know your center point and you know your width/height, which means you you have all the information necessary to implement axis-aligned bounding box (AABB) intersection checks.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your comment. I've added some Information. What you say makes sense to me, but I just can't imagine it in Java, could you help me out there a little bit?

Comment: You might want to include getWidth() and getHeight() methods in your region class.  It will make probable future computations easier.

Comment: You're calculating your width and height incorrectly.  It should be `Rectangle thisRectangle = new Rectangle((int) aX, (int) aY,(int)Math.abs(aX - bX),(int)Math.abs(aY-bY));` where `aX` and `aY` are the upper left corners of the Rectangle.

Comment: Why all the casting? If you're working with int-constrained regions, it's a good idea to make sure aX/aY/etc are already ints. Or, use the `Double` version of rectangle so you don't need int casting, if your coordinates _need_ to be fractional. With that said, if you have points (aX,aY) and (bX,bY), that maps to rectangle(aX, aY, bX-aX, bY-aY), after which the intersection check is already [baked into Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle)). You just return `rect1.intersects(rect2)`, you don't need to calculate anything.

Comment: note: only _if_ your points and b are the upper left and lower point points. If that is _not_ the case, then you're going to need a bunch of preprocessing to first turn the two coordinates you have into "the top-left and bottom-right" coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, some things to point out. First, if you have double values you can use [Rectangle2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html). Second, it handles negative numbers fine.

I would suggest creating a method to convert a region to a Rectangle2D.

```
public Rectangle2D getBounds(Region r){
    double x, w;
    if(r.aX < r.bX ){
      x = r.aX;
      w = r.bX - r.aX;
    } else{
      x = r.bX;
      w = r.aX - r.bX;
    }
    double y, h;
    if(r.aY < r.bY){
      y = r.aY;
      h = r.bY - r.aY;
    } else{
      y = r.bY;
      h = r.aY - r.bY;
    } 
    return new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
}
```

What this is doing, checking to make sure aX, aY and bX, bY are in the correct order, so that x,y is the top left corner of the rectangle and the width and height are positive (or zero) values. I've written it as a method on a region, but you can make it as a method of Region. Such that:

```
public boolean intersects(Region other){
    return getBounds().intersects(other.getBounds());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to approach it.  I am using records which are simply immutable classes.  The same approach would be used for the `Rectangle2D` class in the Java API.  Note that this presumes that the first coordinate in the constructor is the upper left, and the other is the lower right.  You might consider `specifying your region as a bounded area with the upper left coordinates specified along with the width and height`.  It will then be trival to return the other coordinates as required.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class RectangleIntersections {
    
    record Region(int aX, int aY, int bX, int bY) {
        public int getWidth() {
            return bX-aX;
        }
        public int getHeight() {
            return bY-aY;
        }
        public boolean intersects(Region other) {
            return new Rectangle(aX, aY, getWidth(), getHeight()).intersects(
                    new Rectangle(other.aX, other.aY, other.getWidth(), other.getHeight()));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RectangleIntersections().start();
        
    }
    public void start() {
        Region r1 = new Region(0,0, 100,100);
        Region r2 = new Region(50,50, 150,150);
        System.out.println(r1.intersects(r2));
        Region r3 = new Region(101, 101, 110,120);
        System.out.println(r1.intersects(r3));
    }
    
}
```

prints

```
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tested the version from matt and it works perfect. I guess yours would to.

Comment: Of course, if you specify your regions as bounded areas to start with you won't need to compute them.  And the coordinates are easily derived from the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do something like this :

```java
if(Math.abs(thisRectangle.getMaxX()-otherRectangle.getMaxX())<otherRectangle.getWidth()&& Math.abs(thisRectangle.getMaxY()-otherRectangle.getMinY())<otherRectangle.getHeight())
```